# "MisconfigurationError: No TPU devices were found" even when TPU is connected in PyTorch Lightning

Tags: pytorch, tpu, pytorch-lightning

Have been frustrated over the past few hours over a problem, though It's likely its a problem I started myself hah.

I'm trying to connect to the TPU in Colab. I'm pretty sure I've gotten all the import stuff down. My code is [here.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EaCJpyYK8xLuzO79ESAsIlGZAcWjOh8u?usp=sharing) I'm not completely set on everything, so the entire document isn't functional, but you should be able to see my attempts at TPU connection.

I'm running Pytorch in version 1.5.0 and torchvision in 0.6.0 because I was finding I couldn't install XLA with anything later than 1.5.0. I'm running XLA in version 20200325.

This is the image that seems so confusing: It states that we have a connection with xla: 1 yet when trying to flag it in the trainer I get an error saying no TPUs can be found.

[image]

If anyone could help me, that would be amazing.

Thanks,
A

Comment: Just wondering - have you tried installing Torch/Torch-XLA/PyTorch-Lightning using the docs [here](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.5/tpu.html#colab-tpus)? Torch XLA seems to have installed correctly as you mention, but it looks like PyTorch-Lightning needs a few extra steps.

Answer (score 1):

I suffered the same problem, and these steps solved the problem.

1. Follow the PyTorch-Lightning docs: [TPU SUPPORT](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.5/tpu.html#colab-tpus)
2. Add another notebook cell:

```
%%capture
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/xla/master/contrib/scripts/env-setup.py -o pytorch-xla-env-setup.py > /dev/null
!python pytorch-xla-env-setup.py --version nightly --apt-packages libomp5 libopenblas-dev > /dev/null
!pip install pytorch-lightning > /dev/null
```